# How is $\frac{3+5+7 \cdots+(2n+1)}{n}=\frac{2(1+2+3+\cdots+n)+n}{n}$ true?

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

How is $\frac{3+5+7 \cdots+(2n+1)}{n}=\frac{2(1+2+3+\cdots+n)+n}{n}$ true?
when I multiple out, it doesn't make sense. 
How is $\frac{3+5+7 \cdots+(2n+1)}{n}=\frac{2+4+6+\cdots+2n)+n}{n}$ true?

Answer (score 4):

The sum $2+4+6+\cdots+2n$ contains $n$ terms.  So adding $n$ is the same as adding $1$ to every term.  That is,
$$\eqalign{(2+4+6+\cdots+2n)+\color{red}{n}
  &=(2+\color{red}{1})+(4+\color{red}{1})+(6+\color{red}{1})+\cdots+(2n+\color{red}{1})\cr
  &=3+5+7+\cdots+(2n+1)\ .\cr}$$
Now divide both sides by $n$.

Comment: where does the underline n in the edited comment go?

Comment: Why did you want an underline?  I don't understand.

Comment: @ David I got it now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Because $3+5+...+(2n+1)=(1+3+...+2n+1)-1=(n+1)^2-1=n(n+2)$ and

$2(1+2+...+n)+n=2\cdot\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+n=n(n+2)$